# numpy efficient method to create grids around points

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to add black boxes to a numpy RGB image frame array with the shape (4000,4000,3). The center x,y points of the black boxes are in a second numpy array shape (100,2). My issue is I don't know an efficient way in numpy to create a third array of all points that I want to color black that are x,y +/- 2 for every box center point in the second array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to create all the coordinates by offsetting the points' coordinates. Let's try broadcasting:

```
size = 4000

from itertools import product
nbhds = np.array([list(product(np.arange(-2,3), np.arange(-2,3)))])

s = (nbhds + points[:,None] ).reshape(-1,2).clip(0,size-1)
frame[s[:,0], s[:,1]] = 0
```

Trying the above on a small sample:

```
size = 100
frame = np.ones((size,size,3)).astype("uint8")*255 
np.random.seed(42)
points = np.random.randint(0,size,(100,2))
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: I think this is definitely the direction I was looking to go in, thanks. I get the error `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,25,2) (1,100,2) ` when attempting the broadcast `s = (nbhds + points[None,...] )`, is something being left out?

Comment: @LiBrary should be `points[:,None]` instead of `points[None,...]`. updated.